# Sentence structure - "the same girl as ~"

Tags: sentence-construction

Here's the context.

John saw a girl dancing in a bar 3 days ago.

Jihoon saw a girl studying in the library yesterday.

The two girls are the same girl.

In this situation,

> 1. The girl John saw dancing in a bar 3 days ago is the same person as/that Jihoon saw studying in the library yesterday.
> 2. Jihoon saw the same girl studying in the library as/that John saw dancing in a bar.
> 3. John saw a girl dancing in a bar 3 days ago and the girl is the same person that Jihoon saw studying in the library yesterday.

I've made 3 sentences to understand how to use 'the same~' sentence structure. And I think these are all possible to use and the same meaning. Or is there any difference in meaning? And I think as/that are all possible here, but I do agree that there are some people who stick to using only one of them

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36789/difference-between-the-same-as-and-the-same-that This might help you.

Comment: *"Yesterday, Jihoon saw a girl studying in the library, the same girl whom John saw dancing in a bar 3 days ago!"*

Comment: For sentence one, it's not "as" **or** "that". The most complete form would be "as the one that Jihoon saw [. . .}" actually... it sounds better with nothing... "... same person Jihoon saw studying..."

Comment: At a first glance I thought that Jihoon and John were the same person and it was just a spelling mistake. Use visually different names, it'll be easier :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this instance, use "that".

"As" would require an additional phrase:

> Jihoon saw the same girl [studying in the library] **as the one** (that) John saw dancing in a bar.

You can see why this is when you take out the phrase *studying in the library* and even the word "girl". (i.e. You get a basic *same as [x]* construction.)

**Examples:**

> 1. That car is the **same as** Bob's.
> 2. That is the same car **that** Bob has.

Simply put, *...same as...* is a comparison.